# DataAnnotations with GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I created a LINQ TO SQL project to connect with my database and I'd like to bind a list to a gridview in webforms.

If I add the property Browsable(false) in the designer.cs auto-generated code I can see the column disappear in the gridview.

If I, at the contrary, do something like

```
namespace InterfacesDAL
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MasterMetadata))]
    public partial class InterfacesMasterLog : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public class MasterMetadata
        {
            [Browsable(false)]
            public int InterfaceLogID;
        }

    }
}
```

Column is still showing on the gridview.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this tutorial on data annotations and I would recommend going through the entire MVC EF4 tutorial because it's great!

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-6

GridView doesn't have good support for Data Annotations.  WebGrid (System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid) also doesn't have complete support for Annotations.

I would suggest using [MVCContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid).  Below is a good article on how to use it, including how to hide a column automatically `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]`

http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/04/27/mvccontrib-grid-part-7-auto-generated-columns/

Comment: Could you provide a code example or at least the system namespace where NotMapped is defined?

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is the namespace.  I misread your original question.  See my Edited answer.

Comment: Could you provide a code for it? Column is always appearing in my grid!

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comments.  Let me know if it works out for you and if so please mark this as the answer.